# iOS Crash on twitter Oauth

Tags: ios, twitter, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I am using [social.js](https://gist.github.com/rampicos/4320296) and [alloy/social](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy.builtins.social) for Twitter Oauth login in Titanium Appcelerator.

The implementation was working fine but recently it has stopped working on iOS.

It's crashing while twitter authorising, whether running on simulator or device.

Can anyone able to tell me why its crashing and is there any solution available for this problem?

Comment: here is the crash log : https://pastebin.com/5vVYYu6A

Comment: I think this link helps:https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/issues/122

Comment: Thank you Jay, I am not native iOS developer, so can you guide me how to solve this problem?
I have tested it before at 64 bit and its working for me previously.

Comment: Improved the grammar on this question and added a few periods to separate the problem into understandable chunks.